# Scheme merge two lists into one

Tags: scheme

how to design a function that merge two lists into one list.
the first element of first list will be the first element of the new list and the first element of the second list will be the second element of the new list
(a,b,c,d,e,f) (g,h,i) will be (a,g,b,h,c,i,d,e,f,)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The procedure you're trying to implement is known as `interleave` or `merge`. Because this looks like homework, I can't leave you a straight answer, instead I'll point you in the right direction; fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (interleave lst1 lst2)
  (cond ((null? lst1)     ; If the first list is empty
         <???>)           ; ... return the second list.
        ((null? lst2)     ; If the second list is empty
         <???>)           ; ... return the first list.
        (else             ; If both lists are non-empty
         (cons (car lst1) ; ... cons the first element of the first list
               <???>))))  ; ... make a recursively call, advancing over the first
                          ; ... list, inverting the order used to pass the lists.
```

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: I am just guessing but the Downvoter might be objecting to the "because this looks like homework" bit. I had this same question right now and I am using scheme in a work environment. Perhaps the Downvoter was put off by the presumption this is question of homework origin. Again, I am just guessing.

Comment: @xuinkrbin. I doubt it, a _lot_ of my answers are written assuming that the OP is doing a homework and give only hints, like the above. As long as the answer is correct (which it is), there's no reason to downvote it for that

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: I do not disagree giving hints is/can-be good. I am merely suggesting the objection is the public accusation. People generally do not like being accused of nefariousness when actual innocent questions are raised.

Comment: @xuinkrbin. it's not an accusation, but you're right, somebody can take it wrong and maybe get a bit pissed-off, but to tell the truth, the question was so badly formulated and against SO's policies (it doesn't show any effort from OP's part) that it should have been closed

Comment: @xuinkrbin. besides, OP actually _liked_ the answer, that's why he accepted it. Someone else did the downvotes. I'll end up deleting this answer, it seems that no one else liked it :(

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: Can You just edit out the "homework" bit? The answer otherwise strikes Me as a good one but I'm just some random Schmuck.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a purely functional and recursive implementation in `R6RS`

```
(define (merge l1 l2)
      (if (null? l1) l2
          (if (null? l2) l1
              (cons (car l1) (cons (car l2) (merge (cdr l1) (cdr l2)))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to check both lists: Here is a simple version:

```
    (define (interleave lx lz)
  (cond
    [(empty? lx) lz]
    [else (cons (first lx)(interleave lz (rest lx)))]))


(check-expect(interleave '() '())'())
(check-expect(interleave '(X X X X X X) '(O O O O O))
             (list 'X 'O 'X 'O 'X 'O 'X 'O 'X 'O 'X))
(check-expect(interleave '(1 2 3) '(a b c d e f))
             (list 1 'a 2 'b 3 'c 'd 'e 'f))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a simple condition.

```
(define (merge a b)
  (cond ((null? a) b)
        ((null? b) a)
        (else (cons (car a) (merge b (cdr a))))
        ))
```

Comment: It should be (merge (cdr a) b) at the end.