# how to create a string that is composed of alternating letters from 2 strings in scheme?

Tags: scheme

for example: "tom" "hey" becomes "thoemy"
the first letter in the resulting string will always come from the first string.
I have already tried converting the string into a list and trying to recurse, but i always end up in an endless loop.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a job for [`interleave`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12647033/201359). Once you figure out how to implement it (see the linked answer for more details), your procedure will be easy to write:

```
(define (alternate-string str1 str2)
  (list->string
   (interleave (string->list str1)
               (string->list str2))))
```

Of course, it'll work as expected:

```
(alternate-string "tom" "hey")
=> "thoemy"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have many choices here.

The easiest is probably a classical **named let**:

*using a list*

```
(define (alternate-string s1 s2)
  (let loop ((l1 (string->list s1)) (l2 (string->list s2)) (res '()))
    (if (or (null? l1) (null? l2))
        (list->string (reverse res))
        (loop (cdr l1) (cdr l2) (cons (car l2) (cons (car l1) res))))))
```

*using string-append*

```
(define (alternate-string s1 s2)
  (let loop ((l1 (string->list s1)) (l2 (string->list s2)) (res ""))
    (if (or (null? l1) (null? l2))
        res
        (loop (cdr l1) (cdr l2) (string-append res (string (car l1) (car l2)))))))
```

but you could also use the R6RS build-in **fold-left**:

```
(define (alternate-string s1 s2)
  (fold-left
   (lambda (r e1 e2) (string-append r (string e1 e2)))
   ""
   (string->list s1) (string->list s2)))
```

or, if **Racket** syntax is an option:

```
(define (alternate-string s1 s2)
  (for/fold ((res "")) ((c1 s1) (c2 s2))
    (string-append res (string c1 c2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you required to convert to a list?  You could walk the strings and insert their characters one-by-one by operating directly on the strings with `string-ref` and `string-set!`:

```
(define (alternate string1 string2)
  (assert (= (string-length string1) (string-length string2))
  (let ((result (make-string (* 2 (string-length string1)))))
    (let filling ((n 0))
      (when (< n (string-length string1))
        (string-set! result (+ (* 2 n) 0) (string-ref string1 n))
        (string-set! result (+ (* 2 n) 1) (string-ref string2 n))
        (filling (+ n 1))))
     result)))
> (alternate "abc" "123")
"a1b2c3"
```

Note that the `filling` procedures is recursive, tail recursive at that, and properly terminates.